# Debian 10: Network doesn't work anymore after successful netinst installation

Tags: debian, networking

So I've just installed Debian 10 Buster on my HP ProLiant server using the netinst bootable installation. During installation, the network worked flawlessly. For the nameservers, I've chosen 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Debian successfully pulled the needed packages and later rebooted into the new system.

Now, the network won't work anymore. These are some command outputs:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search [given domain name]
nameserver 8.8.8.8
$ ping google.com
^C
$ ping 8.8.8.8
^C
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10ms
```

Any way to reconfigure the network? I don't have net-tools or any network packages installed, only the base OS.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this. I had some initial trouble with the network settings during installation which I had to get fixed with the data center; Debian somehow took the very first network settings I entered (the not-working ones) and put these into the running system. Somehow it used the networking settings I've entered last for the installation, therefore the installation it worked, but it didn't anymore in the running system.

I've had to fix the network files like `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname` etc to resemble the correct network settings. Afterwards, everything worked again.